# Unity3D 5.6 - Build for android - Packaging assets - sharedassets2.assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, apk, assets, packaging

- I have updated to latest unity3d version 5.6
- I am trying to build for android - but I am stuck in the messa : "Packaging assets - sharedassets2.assets".
- Build process never finishes, and it takes almost all cpu resources. I checked taskmanager on windows - there are 4 instances of "Unity Shader Complier" consuming cpu and memory resources.
- I had to kill the process "Unity Editor" to release my computer.

Notes :
* I notices this happen after I decided to use Asset Bundles in my project and I included mobile shaders in graphics settings

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I sloved it,

I was stuck with the message :

"Packaging assets - sharedassets1.assets"

when trying to build for android. because I added some shaders in graphics settings to help with the (missing shaders pink color when testing android builds in pc).

so what I did is, I build all assets bundles with the needed shaders added, then I removed all added shaders (reset settings) - and build apk just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of Project Settings -> Graphics, Always included shaders, before you convert your project, go there and see how many shaders there, after you convert you will see unity will add two new always included shaders, and it can't compile them (lol?), what you need to do is backup file \ProjectSettings\GraphicsSettings.asset and then restore after convert to 5.6. Or delete new shaders manually from "Always included shaders" section.